# Get information about loop in mysql

Tags: mysql

How can I perform loop for data in mysql?

in Oracle I can do this:

```
for i_rec in (Select * from passwords2) loop
     null;
end loop;
```

Is the resembling feature in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

please check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html

```
[begin_label:] LOOP
    statement_list
END LOOP [end_label]
```

You should put your for loop in the statement_list

for loop can be implemented using cursors:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html